# Using ADO to query multiple counts in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I am trying, through ADO to count the number of items in some tables.
The query is the following:

```
select count(*) as a from TABLE1;
select count(*) as b from TABLE2;
```

If I run it through my SQL GUI, I get:

```
a
------------
1
b
------------
0
```

so far so good.

But, if I run this code (VBA):

```
Dim adoCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRecords As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
query ="select count(*) as a from TABLE1;select count(*) as b from TABLE2;"
adoRecords = adoCon.Execute(query)
Debug.Print(adoRecords!a)
Debug.Print(adoRecords!b)
```

It fails on `adoRecords!b` If I check the adoRecords object, the Fields field only has one item, a.

If I run it in two separate queries, it works fine (but I have a important round trip time, so that's bothering...).

How could I get two outputs through ADO?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Maxime

Comment: if you want to list them below each other, use UNION instead of ;

Comment: UNION ALL is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table2
```

and you´ll execute one statement and retrieve 2 rows with 1 column.

Comment: Do UNION ALL instead, in case of same numbers.

Comment: Thank you both. the UNION ALL was indeed very much needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate just one record (as you want) with the count from both tables

```
select (select count(*) from TABLE1) as cntTbl1, (select count(*) from TABLE2) as cntTbl2
```

Union all solution will generate one record on each table, and will need a reference to the table

```
select count(*) as cnt, 'table1' as reference from table1
union all
select count(*),'table2' from table2
```